# what is the difference between these two XQueries

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, basex

I have a huge XML file stored in BaseX. 
Following is the structure of XML nodes

```
Datas   (Parent Node)
  - Data  (Child of above)
     - Desc  (Child of above)
        - P    (Child of above) and contains the actual text
```

`P` tag contains all the text and I have to count the occurrences of specific word which is
inside the `P` tag.

I have created a Full-Text index. Now to count the occurrence of a specific word, I am using following 2 queries

```
ft:count(doc('BHCR')/Datas/Data/Desc[. contains text 'revolution'])
```

This query returns 2177 and took 25 sec.

Another one

```
ft:count(doc('BHCR')/Datas/Data/Desc[text() contains text 'revolution'])
```

This query returns 3684 and took 52 millisec.

Which one is right? Can anybody explain the difference between these two queries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first query, the context item `.` will lead to a merge of all text nodes of an element (i.e., to the creation of its *string value*), which will then be used to find full-text tokens. This merge can result in new keywords. As an example,  the following query will return true...

```
<xml><b>H</b>i</xml>/. contains text 'hi'
```

..where as The following query will return true...

```
<xml><b>H</b>i</xml> contains text 'hi'
```

As the new keywords cannot be stored in the full-text index, no index access takes place, and the query will take much longer.

Your second query will return all `Desc` elements that have `revolution` in their child text nodes. If you want to parse all descending texts of the `Desc` elements, the following query will give you the expected results:

```
ft:count(doc('BHCR')/Datas/Data/Desc[.//text() contains text 'revolution']
```

The [Full Text: Mixed Context](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Full-Text#Mixed_Content) Section in the BaseX documentation will give you more details.

Hope this helps, Christian

Comment: Christian- Thanks for the reply. Hmm now I got it. BTW, your query took 88 ms with 3684 counts. Thanks again:)